# Combinations - picking from groups of (different) identical items

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

*First of all, I apologize if a similar question has been asked before. I did some searching and couldn't find anything here, but there might be an answer floating around somewhere. Basically, this question involves picking a variable number of items out of several groups (with identical items).*

> **Question:**
>
> In Lily's garden there are 9 identical red roses, 6 identical white roses and 4 identical yellow roses. In how many ways can she pick a bouquet containing:
>
> a) At least two red roses?
>
> b) All three colours?

I know that all the possibilities for the way the roses can be picked are
`(9+1)(6+1)(4+1)-1` , as I can (for the red roses) pick either 0, 1, 2... all the way to 9. The same goes for the white and yellow roses, and the -1 is to remove the option where she picks nothing.

To solve Part A, I decided to subtract the possibilities where she picks 0 or 1 red rose, forcing her to pick at least two. I used the equation `8(6+1)(4+1)=280` and **got the question wrong**.

To solve Part B, I used similar logic and decided to subtract the possibilities where she picks 0 roses from all of the three colours. As a result, I denoted this as `(9)(6)(4)=216` and **got it right**.

I'm confused. Can someone explain why the first one is wrong and the second is right?

Comment: Your approach to Part A seems fine to me.  Your teacher would be the best one to ask about what is wrong with the answer in that Part.

Comment: For a we have that the total number of ways is 9*6*4. Subtract this from the number of ways that you can get zero or one roses

Comment: Your answer to part a) looks correct to me.